# Multiple filterings with Schemacrawler?

Tags: grep, schemacrawler

I'd like to filter out multiple patterns, because our schema has superfluous (for the purposes of the intended diagram) table names such as `foo_AUDIT`, `bar_enum_baz`, and `SYSTEM`. So I'd like to hide all tables containing AUDIT, enum, or SYSTEM.

But is that possible? I've tried various usages of `-grepcolumns` and `invert-match` but can only filter out one pattern at a time. My first try was this:

```
-grepcolumns=.*(AUDIT|_enum_|SYSTEM).* \
```

But it appears the underlying regex resolver really is grep-like, and does not support capture groups?

I've tried multiple `-grepcolumns`, but that doesn't appear to work either.

Any solution to this?

For reference this is my invocation so far:

```
    ./schemacrawler.sh \
        -command=schema \
        -grepcolumns=.*\\..*AUDIT\\..* \
        -hideemptytables \
        -infolevel=standard \
        -invert-match \
        -only-matching \
        -portablenames \
        -sortcolumns \
        <...connection options>
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, as soon as I hit post I spot the documentation example:

```
-grepcolumns=.*\.STREET|.*\.PRICE
```

Along with `-invert-match` that works perfectly.

(I got the documentation from running `./schemacrawler.sh --help`)